# Can't resolve ServiceNow incident using REST API

Tags: .net, api, servicenow

I use ServiceNow [REST API](https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/rest_api_doc?v=kingston&id=r_TableAPI-PUT) in my application.

I need to **resolve** existing **incident**.

For this purpose I use `PUT` method and I can update some fields like `short_description`. But if I try to update `state` field then API does not update this field.

I use very simple `C#` code:

```
_restClient.BaseUrl = new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}.service-now.com", serverName));
var request = new RestRequest(string.Format("/api/now/table/incident/{0}", incidentId), Method.PUT)
{
    RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
};
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
request.AddBody(new { state = "6" });
var response = _restClient.Execute(request);
```

I try to update `state` to value `6` because this value is `Resolve`.

But the field is not updated via REST API. However I can Resolve my incident via web UI.

**Why state field is not updated with the use of REST API?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field that you are trying to update should not be read-only.

Comment: It seems you are right... Could you describe in more details how I can change `readonly` property. Maybe you can attach screenshot?

Comment: Go to Dictionary and Dictionary Override.Also look ACLs. Can REST user write to State field?

Comment: Thanks for your attention to the question. It resolves my trouble.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that you are missing out filling the mandatory fields. Make note of all mandatory fields while you resolve an incident through WebUI and add these fields to the body of your PUT request.

You should share the request's responses as well. That could help discover what the problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible causes of behavior of that is that there is  access control lists (ACL) set up on that table. You can read about them for example [here](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/london-platform-administration/page/administer/contextual-security/concept/access-control-rules.html).

In one of the situations I've encountered, there was a special 'flow' of changing states that would forbid changing state of the ticket, unless the "automated_state_flow" parameter was set as false. Might it be the same in your situation? I'd try to send a request with following JSON:

```
{"automated_state_flow"="False";
"state" = "6"}
```

and then sent the second web request:

```
{"automated_state_flow"="False"}
```